# Can't use *ngIF inside *ngFor : angular2

Tags: json, typescript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

i'm using angular2 and i'im binding data from a service , the probleme is when i'm loading data i should filter it by an id , , this is what i'm supposed to do :

```
<md-radio-button
        *ngFor="#item of items_list"
        *ngIf="item.id=1"
        value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}" checked="{{item.checked}}"> {{item.label}}
</md-radio-button>
```

and this is the data:

```
[
  { "id": 1, "value": "Fenêtre" ,"class":"md-primary" ,"label":"Fenêtre" ,"checked":"true"},
  { "id": 2, "value": "Porte Fenêtre" ,"class":"" ,"label":"Porte Fenêtre" }

]
```

by the way i want just the data with id =1 to be accepted , but  i'm seeing this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 14 in [ngIf item.id=1] in RadioFormesType1Component@10:16 ("
        <md-radio-button
                *ngFor="#item of items_list"
                [ERROR ->]*ngIf="item.id=1"
                value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}" checked="{{item.check"): RadioFormesType1Component@10:16
```

so any suggestion to use ngif and ngfor together ?

Comment: Simply, even simpler than the answers : filter the data in your component and you pass it to the view, no need at all to do it in the view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
*ngIf="item.id===1"
```

instead of

```
*ngIf="item.id=1"
```

You try to assign something into the `id` property (operator `=`) instead of testing its value (operator `==` or `===`).

Moreoever both ngFor and ngIf on the same element aren't supported. You could try something like that:

```
<div *ngFor="#item of items_list">
  <md-radio-button
      *ngIf="item.id===1"
      value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}"
      checked="{{item.checked}}">
    {{item.label}}
  </md-radio-button>
</div>
```

or

```
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items_list">
  <md-radio-button
      *ngIf="item.id===1"
      value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}"
      checked="{{item.checked}}">
    {{item.label}}
  </md-radio-button>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks but the problem persists                                                         EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in [item.id===1 in RadioFormesType1Component@11:16]

Comment: In fact you need to create a sub element to apply the `ngIf`. Both `ngFor` and `ngIf` on the same element aren't supported...

Comment: `<template>` tag not working instead I used `<ng-container>`

Answer (score 9):

Another solution is to create custom filtering [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html):

```
import {Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(value, filters) {

    var filter = function(obj, filters) {
      return Object.keys(filters).every(prop => obj[prop] === filters[prop])
    }

    return value.filter(obj => filter(obj, filters[0]));
  }
}
```

and use it like this in component:

```
<md-radio-button
  *ngFor="#item of items_list | filter:{id: 1}"
  value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}" checked="{{item.checked}}"> {{item.label}}
</md-radio-button>
```

Custom pipe needs to be registered on the component:

```
@Component({
  // ...
  pipes: [FilterPipe]
})
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/LK5DsaeYnqMdScQw2HGv?p=preview

Comment: Small correction for Angular 4, you need to add the pipe to the `declarations` array of the module containing the component where you want to use the pipe.

Answer (score 8):

`*ngIf` and `*ngFor` on the same tag are not supported. You need to use the long form with an explicit `<template>` tag for one of them.

**update**

Instead of `<template>` use `<ng-container>` which allows to use the same syntax as inline `*ngIf` and `*ngFor`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="#item of items_list">
  <md-radio-button
        *ngIf="item.id=1"
        value="{{item.value}}" class="{{item.class}}" checked="{{item.checked}}"> {{item.label}}
  </md-radio-button>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: yeah the best solution is to use <template>

Comment: **since update** <ng-container> works like a charm

Comment: Thanks, works great!